# Suppose that $f(x,y) \leq f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^{2}$. Show that $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^2$

Tags: calculus

The question is: Suppose that $f(x,y) \leq f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y)$ in $\textbf{R}^{2}$. Show that $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^{2}$.

I tried searching this question, but all the things I found were about convex functions. We did not learn about that, or partial derivatives yet. The section this is in only encompasses limits of functions of two variables. I am wondering if the professor want us to use the squeeze theorem somehow to show it. Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $f(x,y)\le f(y,x)\le f(x,y)$ means $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$

Comment: What happens if you interchange the symbols $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Applying the rule with, say, $x = 1$ and $y = 2$ gives us $f(1, 2) \le f(2, 1)$. If we apply it again with $x = 2$ and $y = 1$, then $f(2, 1) \le f(1, 2)$. Combined, this yields $f(1, 2) = f(2, 1)$. Note how there isn't anything special about $1$ and $2$.

Comment: If it's true for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ then it is true for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.  And if $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ then $(y,x)\in \mathbb R^2$.  So it is true for any and all $(y,x)$ as well.  So we always have $f(x,y) \le f(y,x)$ but we also have $f(y,x) \le f(y,x)$ because if $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ then $(y,x)\in \mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x,y) \leq f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y)$ in $\textbf{R}^{2},$

then taking $(x,y)=(a,b)$ we have $f(a,b)\le f(b,a),$

and taking $(x,y)=(b,a)$ we have $f(b,a)\le f(a,b)$.

So for all $a,b\in \textbf R, $ we have $f(a,b)\le f(b,a)\le f(a,b)$.

Now if $f(a,b)<f(b,a)$, 
then we would have $f(a,b)<f(a,b),$ which is absurd.

So it must be that $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$ for all $a,b\in \mathbf R.$

Answer (score 0):

The thing is if something is true for all $(x,y)$ then it is true if we simply swap the positions of $x$ and $y$ and it will be true for $(y,x)$ as well.

If it helps you can put a second pair of variables in.  If it's true for any $x=x', y=y'$ then $f(x',y') \le f(y',x')$.  But then it is also true for $x=y'$ and $y=x'$ so $f(y',x') \le f(y',x')$.

But you shouldn't have to do that.

If $f(x,y) \le f(y,x)$ for *all* $x,y$ then $f(y,x) \le f(x,y)$ as well.

So $f(x,y) \le f(y,x) $ and $f(y,x) \le f(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ so $f(y,x) =f(x,y)$ for all $x, y$.